# Set proxy in PhantomJS

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, proxy, phantomjs

I'm having a bit of an issue setting a proxy with PhantomJS, I try to do like this way:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy proxy = new OpenQA.Selenium.Proxy();
proxy.HttpProxy = p;
PhantomJSOptions des = new PhantomJSOptions();
des.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy, proxy);
```

*(p is just a string in a loop for a proxy list, and yes p is getting set correctly)*

But it says element not found when I go to find something on the page because it's navigating to the URL, but the page source it returns is blank as seen here: http://prntscr.com/6hcmz4

Updated Code #1 - No Luck

```
  PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
                service.IgnoreSslErrors = true;
                service.LoadImages = false;
                service.Proxy = p;

                using (var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service))
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: The website is Twitter so they're obviously using SSL (HTTPS) and I've tried both HTTP and HTTPS proxy with the same result :( 

Edit: Also, newest PhantomJS version.

Comment: PhantomJS version 2.0 (From NuGet) also my updated code is up above, I checked IPChicken with it, returns my IP, so it's not setting the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems, with java client but it does not matter.
The fix that i've found is to pass capatibilites via CLI

```html
            ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
            cliArgsCap.add(String.format("--proxy=%s:%s", proxy.getHost(), proxy.getPort()));
            cliArgsCap.add(String.format("--proxy-auth=%s:%s", proxy.getUsername(), proxy.getPassword()));
            cliArgsCap.add("--webdriver=4444");
            cliArgsCap.add("--proxy-type=http");
           desiredCapabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.cli.args", cliArgsCap);
```

The main point is to pass      cliArgsCap.add("--webdriver=4444");
cause there are some issues regarding this 
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12420
https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11619